# for(Room r : ArrayList<Room>) returns empty Room

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist, methods

Im working on something where you can draw rectangles onto images. Its working pretty well, as JavaFX is a breeze, but I am having a small problem I dont seem to understand.

I use the for (object b : ArrayList) all the time and never had this happen to me. Here is the important part of the code:

```
    private void drawRooms() {
    System.out.println("=========================================");
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    boolean bFirst = true;
    double lastX = 0.0, firstX = 0.0, lastY = 0.0, firstY = 0.0;
    gc.setStroke(RED);
    gc.setLineWidth(10);
    System.out.println("alRooms " + alRooms.toString());
    for (Room r : alRooms) {
        System.out.println("r " + r.getCords());
        for (Coordinate c : r.alCords) {
            System.out.println("C " + c.getX());
            if (bFirst) {
                bFirst = false;
                lastX = firstX = c.getX();
                lastY = firstY = c.getY();
            } else {
                gc.strokeLine(lastX, lastY, c.getX(), c.getY());
                lastX = c.getX();
                lastY = c.getY();
            }
        }
        gc.strokeLine(firstX, firstY, lastX, lastY);
        bFirst = true;
    }
}
```

this is where drawRoom() gets invoked, right after creating said room:

```
                        alRooms.add(new Room(txRoomName.getText(), alCords));
                        System.out.println("alRooms size " + alRooms.size());
                        System.out.println("alRoom to string " + alRooms.toString());
                        alCords.clear();
                        drawRooms();
```

Ignore the System.out.println, Ive been using this for debugging. Anyway, here is the console output:

```
Created new CoorRoom asd
[tcp_test_beacon.Coordinate@71afa660, tcp_test_beacon.Coordinate@8227d0c, tcp_test_beacon.Coordinate@1c50a611, tcp_test_beacon.Coordinate@2a467bed]
alRooms size 1
alRoom to string [tcp_test_beacon.Room@26565463]
=========================================
alRooms [tcp_test_beacon.Room@26565463]
r []
```

As you can see, I create a room and add it to alRooms which is an ArrayList. toString() of it, right after adding the room, returns the same as the toString() right before the for() loop. I also get the alCords.toString of the room displayed, which means it has some kind of values.
Afterwards, it gets into the r loop, but getCords() returns nothing. This is already strange, as getCords() of Object Room looks like this:

```
    public ArrayList<Coordinate> getCords(){
    return alCords;
}
```

Afterwards, even thought r.alCords, which is an ArrayList, should exist, it doesnt and the for loop of Coordinate is never executed, as seen by the missing System.out.. What am I looking at here? I think I'm probably missing something extremely obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you snippet, you can see, that you create new `Room` with `Coorinates`:

```
 alRooms.add(new Room(txRoomName.getText(), alCords));
 System.out.println("alRooms size " + alRooms.size());
 System.out.println("alRoom to string " + alRooms.toString());
 alCords.clear();
```

During creation new `Room` you pasing not just new `List`, But Reference to that object! Which you will clear later, before method execution!

alRooms.add(new Room(txRoomName.getText(), **alCords**));
**alCords**.clear();

And later we can see, that your `foeach` staement executed correctly, because you can see this line `r []`. But `List` of `Coordinates` is empty, due of reason above. Just change you code to something like this:

```
 alRooms.add(new Room(txRoomName.getText(), new ArrayList(alCords)));
 System.out.println("alRooms size " + alRooms.size());
 System.out.println("alRoom to string " + alRooms.toString());
 alCords.clear();
```

Comment: You're Awesome. That was exactly the issue! I knew about the Reference stuff, but never quite understood what that means. This is great! Is there any way I could implement it  in here: 

private void setCords(ArrayList<Coordinate> alCords) {
this.alCords = alCords;
}

Comment: @Redimo You can set, like `setCords(ArrayList<Coordinate> alCords) { this.alCords = new ArrayList(alCords); }` Glad to help. Cheers.

Comment: I think I might have stumbled on the same problem again. I have the following snippet:

    `public Room(String sName, double xy[]) {
        this.sName = sName;
        polydouble = xy;
        shapeRoom = new Polyline(polydouble);
        shapeRoom.setFill(TRANSPARENT);
        shapeRoom.setStrokeWidth(3);
        shapeRoom.setStroke(RED);
    }
        
    public Polyline getPoly(){
        return shapeRoom;
    }`

But when I do Room r : alRooms -> r.getPoly(), I get an exception. Even something as simple as inserting `shapeRoom.getPoints());` gives me an exception.

Comment: @Redimo You don't need Java Arrays. Try to change your solution with Lists instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are setting a valid `alCords` and that is not empty. Debug at the line

```
alRooms.add(new Room(txRoomName.getText(), alCords)); // Debug here
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @GensaGames found the error in it! :)